# Saving gps cords into Array

Tags: android, arrays, gps, save, increment

this may sound Very basic but Im really wondering what's the standard.
for collecting GPS cords, and saving Lats and Long in (preferably )an Array, what algorithm brings the best performance ?
is my way any good? any other (better) suggestion?
Thanks

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {  

// new I and J, in increment
 givemeIandJ()

 Array[i][j]=(loc.getLatitude());
 Array[i][j]=(loc.getLongitude());
```

Comment: Why would you even have a two-dimensional array? Do you know what arrays are?

Comment: @323go mmm Dont I need them for saving both Lats and Longs? I want any given point to have a uniqe index

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. And I guess you don't know how arrays work?

Comment: @XaverKapeller you're wrong

Comment: Care to elaborate? You are assigning both the longitude and latitude to the same element in the array therefore overriding one value with the other, how does this happen if you know how arrays work?

Comment: @XaverKapeller If only you would put your precise time on the question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best performance by means of memory saving is to store lat and longitude in different arrays:

```
int[] longitudes = new int[maxSize];
int[] latitudes  = new int[maxSize];

longitudes[i] = loc.getLongitude() * 1E7; / 1E7 = 1000000: converts to integer
latitudes[i] = loc.getLatitdue() * 1E7;
```

where `maxSize` could be the max buffer size before you write to storage.

Two dimensional arrays in java need more space (than in C) because a 2d array is an 1d array of objects of type int[], which looses 20 bytes per (1-d) entry.

If you want, you can store the lat/lon even in one int[] array:

```
int[] latLongs= new int[2 * maxSize];

latLongs[2*i] = (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E7);
latLongs[2*i + 1] = (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E7);
```

If you want to ommit the faktor 1E7, just use double[] (or float[]) array.

Comment: Weel explained. but about the increment of index: simply incrementing them on every call is ok?

Comment: yes, once you receive a location from the location API, increment the buffer index, and store the location. make sure the index does not exceed the max size.